# Assigning variables through a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, for-loop, automation

I'm trying to use a for loop to assign values to variables - in this case the variables are all called: 'die1', 'die2', 'die3', etc.

```
import random
for i in range(5):
    die[i] = random.randint(1,6)
```

What i'm trying to achieve is ending up with 5 variables assigned with a random number. I've tried a few different ways but end up with either 'die' variable not been assigned or that I'm not able to use 'i' or another variable that I count up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your interpreter, `die1`, `die2`, etc. are unrelated entities. If they should be grouped as in your case, consider a `list`:

```
die = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(5)]
```

Now you can access `die[0]`, `die[1]`, etc. If you really need independent variables, you can use:

```
die1, die2, die3, die4, die5 = [random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(5)]
```

This, however, will raise an error if the number of variables on the left does not match the length of the `list`/`tuple` on the right. For flexibility reasons, I would recommend using a list.

Comment: Is there any possible way to not use a list, and just store them as seperate variable? 

I have a list later that looks like this:
`dice = [die1, die2, die3, die4, die5] `

And later functions are called as such:
`dice[i]`

With 'i' being controlled through a for loop

Comment: This is the elegant solution.

Comment: @Tym You could just create your `dice` list as indicated here. There should be no justifiable need to first create independent variables if you then stuff them into a list anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)! The reason I'm using them is just because I'm not very confident with lists... Poor excuse, I know...

Comment: @Tym: Well you should _get confident_ by practicing using lists! :) Write _lots_ of tiny programs that use lists until you're comfortable with how they behave. Lists are very important, especially in Python, which has several powerful features for handling lists. When code has a bunch of numbered variables like `die1, die2, die3, die4, die5` it almost _always_ should be using a list or tuple (or possibly a dict) instead. Using a bunch of numbered variables makes the code bigger  and more confusing than it needs to be, making it harder to develop & maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the goal is to fill a list named `die`, then you can define it and append the integers at each iteration:

```
import random

die = []
for _ in range(5):
    die.append(random.randint(1, 6))
```

If you mean to different variables, you can define them dynamically using [vars](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#vars):

```
import random

die1, die2, die3, die4, die5 = [0] * 5
for i in range(5):
    vars()['die{}'.format(i)] = random.randint(1, 6)
```

The line defining the local variables is not mandatory though it'll be easier to work with in an IDE.

*If you mean to the first part, or to the second part with few variables, I think that schwobaseggl's solution is more elegant.*

Comment: Thanks for the response! Mind me asking why you used '_' in the first for look for the looping variable, but 'i' for the second? Also - what's the importance of including vars() in the second part?

Comment: In the first loop, `i` is not used - a common convention in python is to name this kind of variables with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest making a fixed size list that you assign to so it doesn't grow each time you call `append`.

```
import random

die = [0] * 5

def roll():
    for i in range(5):
        die[i] = random.randint(1, 6)
```

Now you can call `roll` and the die list is updated.

Comment: Why is it bad for the list to grow?  Isn't it worse to fill up memory with zeros unnecessarily?

Comment: @zondo I am assuming he wants a list of 5 numbers. If using append each call to roll will  append 5 new numbers to the list thereby growing it. The list of five numbers (initially zero) is updated with new values each call to roll. So there is no memory fill and no new list is created every time.

Comment: No new list is created anyway.  If you don't like the idea of a growing list, use a list comprehension: `die = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]`

Comment: @ThomasChristensen Actually, `append` does not create a new list, at least not every time ;) . Appending is O(1): https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @zondo list comprehensions creates a new list each time it is evaluated right?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I know :-) append just grows the list. List comprehensions creates a new. My idea was a fixed sized list that just gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of variables are large it might be not possible to mention all variable names at the beginning. Instead they could be created at each iteration of the for-loop and stored in a dictionary as keys while the random numbers associated with them can be stored as their values in the dictionary.

You could use string joining for creating variable names eg `'die'+'1' = 'die1'` . If you call 'die1' as 'n' then you add a new key to the dictionary as `Dict[n]=randint(1,6)` where randint(1,6) is the value corresponding to 'die1'. This way you can easily use these variables for mathematical operations.

```
from random import randint
Dict={}
count=1
for i in range(5):
    n='die'+str(count)
    DICT[n]=randint(1,6)
    count=count+1
    print DICT
print DICT['die1'],DICT['die2']
print DICT['die1']+DICT['die2']
```